# One event listener establishes another event listener, but both are triggered by the first event. Why?

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble understanding when/how event listeners are added and have tried to illustrate my general question through this little snippet.

If the toggle button has a `mousedown` event, then the little box toggles between being displayed or not displayed.  Also, if displayed then for a `mousedown` event anywhere in the document the box will change to not displayed.

My question is why won't it work if `evt.stopPropagation` is commented out?

If both `.evt.stopPropagation` and the `document.addEventListener` are commented out then the toggle works as expected, but only for the button, and the box is not removed from display for `mousedown` on the document.

If a console.log message is placed inside the `clear` function when the event listener on the document is active and `evt.stopPropagation` is commented out, it can be seen that the `mousedown` on the button also triggers the `mousedown` on the document. So, clicking the toggle button displays and removes from display at the same time, and the box is never seen.

I was expecting the button event to add the event listener on the document after its own event, such that the document couldn't register a `mousedown` event for the first event on the button because it wasn't yet declared; but it appears that both listeners are set up at the same time.

Could you please explain?  Thank you for considering my question.

```js
"use strict";

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener( 'mousedown', display, false );

function display( evt )
  {
    evt.stopPropagation();
  
    let e = evt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
    if ( e.style.display === 'block' )
      {
        e.style.display = 'none';
      }
    else
      {
        e.style.display = 'block';      
        document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', clear, false );            
      }; // end if
  } // close display
  
function clear()
  {
    document.removeEventListener( 'mousedown', clear, false );
    document.querySelector('button').nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none';    
  }
```

```css
div {
 display: none;
 background-color: rgb(150,150,150);
 border: 1px solid black;
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button>Toggle</button>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@traktor53's answer correctly identified what happens, but I fear their explanation is not clear enough.

What you are experiencing here is basically caused by two facts:

- MouseEvents do bubble to their ancestors.
- EventTarget.addEventListener is a synchronous method.

To understand better, I will avoid speaking about the capture phase for now.

So when a browser is to dispatch an Event on a target, it will first check all the handlers it has to call on that target, then execute all these handlers, and finally bubble up the DOM to the window (of course, only in case of bubbling event).

Taking your example, we can schematize this bubbling phase like so:

```
[<button>] ->  list of handlers: [`ƒ display`]
               execute `ƒ display` // (add handler on document)
               continue with parentNode
[<body>]   ->  list of handlers: none
               continue with parentNode
[<html>]   ->  list of handlers: none
               continue with ownerDocument
[document] ->  list of handlers: [`ƒ clear`] // (added in `display`)
               execute `ƒ clear`
               continue with defaultView
[window]   ->  list of handlers: none
```

As you can see, the EventHandler you add on `document` is added **before** the algorithm got to check what are the EventHandlers attached to `document`. So when the Event is to fire on the `document` EventTarget, the latter will have this EventHandler attached to itself.

To demonstrate it, we can even build this ladder code, which will add an EventListener to all the ancestors of the original target from inside the first EventHandler:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('mousedown', handle, {once:true});

function handle(evt) {
  console.log('firing from', this.toString());
  const up = this.defaultView || // window for document
    this.parentNode || // elements until html
    this.ownerDocument; // html
  if(up) up.addEventListener('mousedown', handle, {once:true});
}
```

```html
<button>click me</button>
```

Doing so, your `clear` function will get called right after `display` got called, reverting immediately what `display` had done.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The item that I did not understand is what you provided in your earlier comment, and ,if I understand you correctly, when the first event takes place all the snynchronous code in the handler is executed completely before any bubbling takes place.  I was expecting the event to immediatly bubble before the handler's code was executed.  How can the new event be added only after the bubbling has completed instead of stopping the bubbling?  I tried a setTimeout in my code, not snippet, and it didn't work. I want the button event to bubble for other purposes. Thanks.

Comment: @Gary there is only a single event. The browser's rule for executing all the handlers are simply to start with [capture phase] window => document ... currentTarget => [bubbling-phase] => currentTarget => currentTarget.parentNode ... window. At every step, it will check if the node of this step has such event handlers, and execute them all before going to the next step, if stopPropagation() has not been called. Now, calling `clear` in  a setTimeout does fix the issue, there must be something else here: https://jsfiddle.net/z742jyne/

Comment: Thank you for the example.  It does work for one.  I tried to do the same with a two-button scenario, each with a box.  I wanted clicking the second button to both display its box and bubble to the document listener to remove the first button's box.  But that seems to cause more trouble than using event.stopPropagation and invoking a function to clear all displayed boxes.

Answer (score 1):

In the [bubbling phase](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-flow), events bubble up the DOM from the target element which generated the event, via the chain of elements' parent nodes, to the `document` object and from there to `window`:

[image]
[Source 3.1 *figure*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20090908/#event-flow)

Calling `event.stopPropagation` in a handler stops the event bubbling any further up the DOM (of course).

Now if the next sibling of the toggle is not on display, the `display` event handler stops propagation, shows the next element and registers a listener on the document node to hide the element again.

*If `stopPropagation` is not called, the `mousedown` event continues to bubble up the DOM looking for "mousedown" listeners to call.* It finds the one added by `display` to the document node ( i.e. the 'clear` function), calls it, and handler execution hides the next element after the toggle.

You never get to see the next element in the brief period between calling the `mousedown` handler for `button` and that for `document`, and if processing the event bubbling blocks screen update, you never will.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I understand the concept of bubbling and what stopPropagation does.  What I don't understand is why there is an event listener on the document to bubble up to, when it hasn't yet been added following the first button event.  The document-level event listener is added after the button event; so, how can the button event bubble up to the document event listener on the very first click of the button? It reminds me of the situation of why an indexedDB request is made before the success and error events are declared. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds a bit complicated of an explanation... @Gary put in simpler words, at the time `display` adds the event listener on the document, the event is firing on <button>, it still has to make its way through <body>, <html>, and then to `document`. So if you did add listeners to these elements, they would fire too, from the same event that triggered `display`. When you don't stop the event from propagating, you are always gonna call `clear` right after `display` executed. https://jsfiddle.net/8cuprghy/

Comment: @Kaido Do you mean that during the time it takes for the event to bubble from the button to the document the event listener gets added to the document?

Comment: @Gary Well yes, that's what your code asks the computer to do. `addEventListener` is a synchronous method.

Comment: @Kaido I asked the computer to add the event listener to the document after the button  mousedoiwn event. So, at least on the very first button mousedown, why is there a document listener in place for the button's event to bubble up to?  I could understand it if the document event listener was added at the same time the button event was added.  Shouldn't the button mousedown event have completed before the document listener gets added?

Comment: @Gary "*I asked the computer to add the event listener to the document **after** the button mousedown event*" No, that's probably where your confusion comes from. Your code is executed from inside the Event handler. So when it gets executed, the Event is still very alive, you are not asking it to add the new listener ***"after"***, but precisely *inside* this event. So when the execution of button's handler finishes, the one on `document` is already in place, and fires too.

Comment: @Kaido, You're right, that's what I wasn't understanding.  Thank you.

Comment: Another way of examining it is that [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) is synchronous - all event bubbling must complete (or `stopPropagation` called)  for `dispatchEvent` to determine its return value. An event listener added  synchronously higher in the DOM, by a listener lower in the DOM  for the same event, will be encountered and executed by `dispatchEvent` processing. The added event listener is not saved anywhere and somehow added asynchronously some time later.