# addEventListener stops listening after element is updated with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, addeventlistener

This is my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function init() {
            var el = document.getElementById('mydiv2');
            el.addEventListener('click', function() {
                console.log('clicked');
            });
        }
        function getcontent() {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onload = function() {
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                    //init();
                }
            }
            xhr.open("GET", "content.txt", true);
            xhr.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <div id="mydiv">
        <div id="mydiv2">Some content</div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="getcontent()">Get new content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

After the document loads, init() is executed and adds a click listener to the div "mydiv2". When the button is clicked, getcontent() gets some content a replaces "mydiv" with the new content.

```
<div id="mydiv2">New content</div>
```

Replacing the old div with a new one, even with the same id, breaks the binding with the listener.
My workaround is to simply add init() to the xhr.onload event (after the innerHTML replacement), so the listener is re-attached.
I want to know if I'm missing something or there is a better solution.

Comment: The issue is the event it attached to the element.  You're replacing the element, thus the binding is lost with the destruction of the original element

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're adding the `click` event listener to the element that is removed from the dom after the XHR request is completed:

```
    function init() {
        /* el has id of mydiv2 */
        var el = document.getElementById('mydiv2');

        /* click event added to mydivd2 */
        el.addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log('clicked');
        });
    }

    ...

    /* Parent of mydiv2 (ie mydiv) has contents replaced, which removes mydiv2 */        
    document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
```

To resolve this, consider attaching the `click` event to a DOM element that is unaffected by the XHR request, such as the button:

```
    function init() {

        /* Obtain the button and add the click event to that instead */
        var el = document.querySelector('button');
        el.addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log('clicked');
        });
    }
```

Comment: As someone pointed out to me a few months ago, it may be a good practice to place the event listeners as high up in the DOM as you can and condition them using the `matches` method.  It reduces the number of listeners needed and helps with handling propagation since the listener is higher up.  Several different events can be listened for on the same parent and mapped to a handler based on the child element on which the event took place.  It required a bit of different thinking but certainly made my code more efficient and better overall.

Comment: @Gary thanks for that, sounds interesting :) - what is the `matches` method?

Comment: I forgot to mention that where it initially helped me was when one event declared another event, such as when a drop-down button is clicked and an event added to remove the drop down when click anywhere on the page.  If the listeners are placed higher up in the DOM, you don't have to add and remover the second listener.

Comment: It lets you test the element using CSS type selectors.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches. I'll try to find the post that gave the example to me also,

Comment: wow thanks for that @Gary! didn't know about this, looks super useful! thanks again :)

Comment: You're welcome. The selected answer from Brad to this question gives a basic example of how `matches` is used with an event handler on a parent element: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56094898/how-to-test-html-elements-for-unique-identity-without-assigning-an-id.

Comment: The selected answer to this question gives an explanation of how an event is handled in terms of how propagation works.  If you read it, you will see that Kaiido had to explain to me where I was misunderstanding how an event can be added to a parent element before the event even propagates to the parent. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55446351/one-event-listener-establishes-another-event-listener-but-both-are-triggered-by. Sounds simple but when you don't know, like I didn't, it can waste a few hours of your time.